# regex value to string

Tags: .net, vb.net

I wish to use regex to match a link and put the first one into the string.

I don't know why below code only show nothing.

Please help me.

```
Private Sub Info_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Info.Click

        dim theusercp as string = "http://google.com/abcd/12345"

        Dim pattern As String = "http://.*.com"
        Dim rs As String = Regex.Match(theusercp, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline).Groups(1).Value


        urlbase.Text = rs
'Display the string in label1
        MessageBox.Show(rs)
'I hoped it to show "http://google.com" but the result is blank.

    End Sub
```

Comment: try using http:\/\/.*.com or simply http:.*.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you refer to `Groups(1)`, but there are no [groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your regular expression! Just return the matched value directly:

```
Dim rs As String = Regex.Match(theusercp, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline).Value
```

This will yield the desired output.

*As a side note: Your pattern will also match `http://example.com/xcom` in `http://example.com/xcom/123`. I'm not sure this is what you indended...*